# CakePHP 3.x: routes with query string

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

Named parameters were finally removed with CakePHP 3. Now I want to know if there is an easy way to create routes that use the query string.

Now I have:

```
http://mysite/posts?page=2
```

While I would like:

```
http://mysite/posts/2
```

I have read the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html), but I have not found useful examples.

When I say "an easy way", I mean precisely by using a route, not the controller or the paginator.

---

**EDIT:**
I know I can do this:

```
$routes->connect('/posts/:page', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index'], ['page' => '[0-9]+', 'pass' => ['page']]);
```

Controller:

```
public function index() {
    if($this->request->param('page'))
        $this->request->query['page'] = $this->request->param('page');

    //other code...
}
```

But in this way I need:

1. to modify my controller;
2. to modify the paginator (the new url works, but it is not used automatically by CakePHP).

Comment: The paginator [uses query args](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php#L261) - The re-inventing of get arguments was eventually decided to have been a bad idea, and the paginator code now expects get arguments only. You'll need to [create a route class](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes-for-resource-routes) (which is not hard to do) to simulate get arguments to do exactly what you ask - but I caution not to do that, and use urls/get arguments/the paginator as designed.